# On hover and click of label do something

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a label and I want to do some actions on hover and click but the below code is not working.

```
class LoginForm:
    def __init__(self,root):    
        Label(text='Don\'t have an account? Create one!', font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)
        Label.bind( "<Button>",self.mouseClick)
    def mouseClick(self,event):
        print('x')
```

And I got the next error
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_bind'`
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: On hover,maybe you should bind `<Enter>`.You should bind event for a widget.Your code is invalided.

Comment: `Label.bind( "<Enter>",self.mouseClick)` you mean like this? If yes, I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might be:

```
class LoginForm:
    def __init__(self,root):    
        exmpleText_widget = Label(text='Don\'t have an account? Create one!', font='Arial 10') # assgin it to a variable 
        exmpleText_widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)
        # exmpleText_widget.bind( "<Button>",self.mouseClick) # This is mouse button event,All the mouse button pressed on this widget will call the function.
        exmpleText_widget.bind("<Enter>",self.mouseClick) # This can be an easy mouse hover event
        exmpleText_widget.bind("<Button-1>",function) # mouse left button pressed on this widget will call the function.
        # exmpleText_widget.bind("<Leave>",function) # this will call the function when mouse leave this widget.
    def mouseClick(self,event):
        print('x')
```

Comment: It shows up this error using your code `AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind' ` Do I have to import something in my projects for `binds`?

Comment: It is working now. I just had to split `Label(text='Don\'t have an account? Create one!', font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)` in two lines

Comment: @Viorel No,You should use `var = Label(text='Don\'t have an account? Create one!', font='Arial 10')` and `var.place()`.Read it [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name).My fault,I made a careless mistake.I edited my post.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.